# Framework7 and Vue typescript typings conflict

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, typescript-typings, html-framework-7

[The Framework7 docs](https://framework7.io/vue/init-app.html) say:

```
// First of all, we need to initialize/enable Framework7 Vue plugin:
// We need to pass Framework7Vue plugin and Framework7 as an arguments to Vue.use method
Vue.use(Framework7Vue, Framework7);
```

[and in at least one place](https://framework7.io/docs/app.html#app-events), indicating that the default export of 'framework7' (here, `Framework7`) is a constructor function or class, not an object:

> Automatically after `new Framework7()` ...

And [the Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use) say:

> Vue.use(plugin)
>
> Arguments: {Object | Function} plugin
>
> Usage: Install a Vue.js plugin. If the plugin is an Object, it must expose an
> install method. If it is a function itself, it will be treated as the
> install method. The install method will be called with Vue as the
> argument.
>
> When this method is called on the same plugin multiple times, the
> plugin will be installed only once.

And [the vue.d.ts type definitions](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/types/vue.d.ts#L113) say:

```
use<T>(plugin: PluginObject<T> | PluginFunction<T>, options?: T): void;
```

Which means that the following would be the typed version:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Framework7 from 'framework7'
import Framework7Vue from 'framework7-vue'

Vue.use<Framework7>(Framework7Vue, Framework7); // only adding the type parameter, which eventually might not be necessary once the rest is correct
```

The untyped version seems to work correctly, but I can't resolve the right Typescript definitions for Framework7 - perhaps central on the `Framework7` value argument to `.use()`.  The default export of 'framework7' can't be both a constructor function AND an instance of itself, but I think it would have to be if all these docs are true.  I can't figure out where the discrepancy is.

My work is in these repos:

- https://github.com/JasonKleban/Framework7.d.ts
- https://github.com/JasonKleban/framework7-vue.d.ts

I might suspect the vue.d.ts since both `new Framework7()` elsewhere and passing `Framework7` as an instance, an `options` object to `.use()` work.  Are the vue.d.ts definitions wrong in that they'll also accept a function or a constructor?  But there are too many possibilities for me to reason out - I'm hoping someone more familiar with vue.js and/or framework7 can untangle this for me.